# Compare two array objects and get changed object using functional javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, functional-programming

I'm trying to get the difference of two array objects based on `workscopeThreshold` and `customerThreshd`

```
var array1 = {
  "family": "ABC",
  "globalThreshold": "2.0",
   "spiData": [
    {
      "customerName": "AIR CANADA",
      "customerThreshold": "4.0",
      "workscopes": [
        {
          "id": "21",
          "workscopeName": "1 - QT - Quick Turn",
          "wokscopeThreshold": "7.0"
        },
        {
          "id": "22",
          "workscopeName": "2 - SV - Light",
          "wokscopeThreshold": "8.0"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "customerName": "AIR CHINA",
      "customerThreshold": "8.0",
      "workscopes": [
        {
          "id": "10",
          "workscopeName": "1 - QT - Quick Turn",
          "wokscopeThreshold": "6.0"
        },
        {
          "id": "11",
          "workscopeName": "2 - SV - Light",
          "wokscopeThreshold": "7.0"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}



 var array2 = {
      "family": "ABC",
      "globalThreshold": "2.0",
       "spiData": [
        {
          "customerName": "AIR CANADA",
          "customerThreshold": "4.0",
          "workscopes": [
            {
              "id": "21",
              "workscopeName": "1 - QT - Quick Turn",
              "wokscopeThreshold": "7.0"
            },
            {
              "id": "22",
              "workscopeName": "2 - SV - Light",
              "wokscopeThreshold": "8.0"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "customerName": "AIR CHINA",
          "customerThreshold": "8.0",
          "workscopes": [
            {
              "id": "10",
              "workscopeName": "1 - QT - Quick Turn",
              "wokscopeThreshold": "6.0"
            },
            {
              "id": "11",
              "workscopeName": "2 - SV - Light",
              "wokscopeThreshold": "877.0"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

In array2 I've changed customerThreshold of id:11 to 877. Hence in the final object I would like to get that changed object only inside `workscopes` array of 'AIR CHINA' ie., remove objects that have same `customerThreshold` .Same method goes in case of `customerThreshold`.

I've tried code as shown below but it keeps similar objects of last index.Not sure where I'm doing wrong.Any solution with functional javascript would be very helpful

```
function remove_duplicates(a, b) {
            for (let i = 0, len = a.length; i < len; i++) {
                for (let j = 0, len2 = b.length; j < len2; j++) {
                    if (a[i].id === b[j].id && a[i].customerThreshold === b[j].customerThreshold) {
                        b.splice(j, 1);
                        len2 = b.length;
                    }
                }
            }
            return b;
        }
         const test = oldObj.spiData.forEach(oldSpi => {
            newObj.forEach(newSpi => {
                const uniqueWorkscope = remove_duplicates(oldSpi.workscopes, newSpi.workscopes);
                return oldSpi.workscopes = uniqueWorkscope;
            });
        });
```

Expected result if only 'workscopeThreshold' is changed

```
var expectedResult1 = {
      "family": "ABC",
      "globalThreshold": "2.0",
       "spiData": [        
        {
          "customerName": "AIR CHINA",
          "customerThreshold": "8.0",
          "workscopes": [           
            {
              "id": "11",
              "workscopeName": "2 - SV - Light",
              "wokscopeThreshold": "877.0"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

Expected result if `customerThreshold` and `workscopeThreshold` is changed for in different array objects.
PS :I've changed `customerThreshold` of AIR CANADA to 5756

```
 var expectedResult2= {
      "family": "ABC",
      "globalThreshold": "2.0",
       "spiData": [
        {
          "customerName": "AIR CANADA",
          "customerThreshold": "5756",
          "workscopes": []
        },
        {
          "customerName": "AIR CHINA",
          "customerThreshold": "8.0",
          "workscopes": [             
            {
              "id": "11",
              "workscopeName": "2 - SV - Light",
              "wokscopeThreshold": "877.0"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: please add the result as well.

Comment: @NinaScholz Please find the expected result .If both `customerThreshold` and `wokscopeThreshold` is changed,that changed entity only need to be shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) can be combined to cheaply / functionally `return` the differences between new and old `Arrays` of nested `Objects`.

```js
// Original Data.
const array1 = {
  "family": "ABC",
  "globalThreshold": "2.0",
   "spiData": [
    {
      "customerName": "AIR CANADA",
      "customerThreshold": "4.0",
      "workscopes": [
        {
          "id": "21",
          "workscopeName": "1 - QT - Quick Turn",
          "wokscopeThreshold": "7.0"
        },
        {
          "id": "22",
          "workscopeName": "2 - SV - Light",
          "wokscopeThreshold": "8.0"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "customerName": "AIR CHINA",
      "customerThreshold": "8.0",
      "workscopes": [
        {
          "id": "10",
          "workscopeName": "1 - QT - Quick Turn",
          "wokscopeThreshold": "6.0"
        },
        {
          "id": "11",
          "workscopeName": "2 - SV - Light",
          "wokscopeThreshold": "7.0"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}


// New Data.
const array2 = {
  "family": "ABC",
  "globalThreshold": "2.0",
   "spiData": [
    {
      "customerName": "AIR CANADA",
      "customerThreshold": "4.0",
      "workscopes": [
        {
          "id": "21",
          "workscopeName": "1 - QT - Quick Turn",
          "wokscopeThreshold": "7.0"
        },
        {
          "id": "22",
          "workscopeName": "2 - SV - Light",
          "wokscopeThreshold": "8.0"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "customerName": "AIR CHINA",
      "customerThreshold": "8.0",
      "workscopes": [
        {
          "id": "10",
          "workscopeName": "1 - QT - Quick Turn",
          "wokscopeThreshold": "6.0"
        },
        {
          "id": "11",
          "workscopeName": "2 - SV - Light",
          "wokscopeThreshold": "877.0"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}


// Differences.
const workscopeDifferences = (ORIGINAL, NEW) => ({
  family: NEW.family,
  globalThreshold: NEW.globalThreshold,
  spiData: NEW.spiData.reduce((differences, object) => (!JSON.stringify(ORIGINAL.spiData).includes(JSON.stringify(object)) && [...differences, {...object, workscopes: object.workscopes.filter((scope) => !JSON.stringify(ORIGINAL.spiData).includes(JSON.stringify(scope)))}] || differences), [])
})


// Log.
console.log(workscopeDifferences(array1, array2))
```

Comment: Can we remove object with `"id": "10",` as it's `wokscopeThreshold` is same ?

Comment: My bad. I wasn't sure what you wanted. How's that?

Comment: No prob :-) Since the object with "id": "10" has no difference in its `wokscopeThreshold`  my question was we can exclude the same as well and keeping only the changed object ie.,"id": "11",which is currently shown and correct

Comment: Thanks @Arman.The solution works great for differences at workscope level.I would also like to exclude object if there is no difference at `customerThreshold` level as mentioned in the question.ie,, in the console solution can we exclude `{
      "customerName": "AIR CANADA",
      "customerThreshold": "4.0",
      "workscopes": []
    },` since there's no change in `customerThreshold` or `wokscopeThreshold` for AIR CANADA. Thanks again

Comment: Sure. Updated 

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166582/discussion-between-forgottofly-and-arman-charan).